# execute ping command with GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

While writing a GUI application in PyQt5 I encounter weird(for me) behavior.
When I wanted to open an information window and start doing another thing after it fully loads. I noticed that the information window does not load fully until the next block of code is done.

**This is how it looks**

[image]

**Code that reproduces this unwanted behavior**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMessageBox
import sys
import os
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

box = QMessageBox()
box.setText("Text")
box.show()
os.system("ping 8.8.8.8 ")


sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Behavior is the same whether I use QMessegBox, inherit it in another class or write my own QMeesgeBox type class.

I guess this behavior works like this because of os.system() function and I would use Process or Thread to make a workaround, but if It is possible I would like to ensure that window is fully loaded and then the next procedure is taking place.

Python version 3.7.0

PyQt5 version 5.12.1

Comment: You did not add a parent to the message box, it may be because of that?

Comment: I got the same error when a parent was set.

Comment: @AdrianBaczyński Check my answer since S.Nick's answer is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the solutions of S.Nick and Guimoute seems to work but the reality is that it has only made the window show a moment but if you want to interact with it you will see that it is frozen, for example try to move the window to check it. The `os.system()` task is blocking so it must be executed in another thread

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMessageBox

import threading
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

box = QMessageBox()
box.setText("Text")
box.show()

def task():
    os.system("ping 8.8.8.8 ") 
threading.Thread(target=task, daemon=True).start()
# or threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=("ping 8.8.8.8 ",), daemon=True).start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or use QProcess:

```py
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

box = QMessageBox()
box.setText("Text")
box.show()

def on_readyReadStandardOutput():
    print(process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode(), end="")

process = QProcess()
process.start("ping", ["8.8.8.8"])
process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(on_readyReadStandardOutput)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Update

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class PingObject(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        os.system("ping 8.8.8.8")
        self.finished.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    box.setText("Text")
    box.show()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    thread.start()
    ping = PingObject()
    ping.moveToThread(thread)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, ping.start)
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    ping.finished.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    print("finished ping")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Another Option:**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        response = os.popen("ping 8.8.8.8")
        for line in response.readlines():
            print(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    box.setText("Text")
    box.show()

    thread = Thread()
    thread.start()
    ret = app.exec_()
    thread.quit()
    thread.wait()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: Thread version of your program is not working for me, It is blocking in the same way. QProcess() approach is blocking os.system while the window is moved on the screen.

Comment: @AdrianBaczyński How strange, are you executing my code without modifying it? maybe you have modified it incorrectly

Comment: Yes you right, the "join()" function on the thread cause that behavior.

Comment: @AdrianBaczyński join blocks the thread where the thread was thrown so now the block is not by os.system() but by join, in a GUI you should not use join since the eventloop fulfills a similar function

Comment: Can You advise me how can I use your thread code to wait until the thread work is done?

Comment: @AdrianBaczyński In this case with threading.Thread is complicated but using a QObject with QThread the task is simpler, try my update

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single-line solution:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMessageBox
import sys
import os
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

box = QMessageBox()
box.setText("Text")
box.show()
QApplication.processEvents() # <------------ this one
os.system("ping 8.8.8.8 ")

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The window is still blocked but the behavior is the closest to the one I wanted

Comment: processEvents is just a fake solution, for example try to move the window, you will see that the window is frozen

Comment: @eyllanesc OP wanted the window to be fully loaded before carrying on with other tasks, there is no specification about the window being responsive.

Comment: @Guimoute IMHO the responsive capacity of the window is a requirement for all GUI, no one likes a frozen GUI. So it is not necessary to be explicit in it.

Answer (score 0):

As an option. Try it:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

box = QMessageBox()
box.setText("Text")
box.show()

def osSystem():
    os.system("ping 8.8.8.8 ") 

QTimer.singleShot(20, osSystem )

#os.system("ping 8.8.8.8 ")


sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the best way to wait after this line "QTimer.singleShot(20, osSystem )" end?

Comment: Your method is incorrect, for example, it prevents the window from moving